# How can I display all values in one row MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, The first table contains the following structure:
user_id, date_in, time_in.

the second table contains the following structure:
user_id, date_out, time_out.

Because there is a user_id in each table which will always have a match I can use a join the query the database.

So this is my current query.

```
SELECT staff_in.date_in
     , time_in 
     , staff_out.date_out
     , time_out 
  FROM staff_in 
  LEFT 
  JOIN staff_out 
    ON staff_in.user_id = staff_out.user_id
```

all the results appear on seperate lines, I want to display all the results on the same line, how can I do this?

Comment: one line you mean if you have 1000+ rows you want them in one single row ?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I mean pal.

Comment: You need to use GROUP_CONCAT and then GROUP BY

Comment: This doesn't seem very practical.

Comment: I know it doesn't seem very practical but I will never be displaying the whole of the results as I will have a between dates at the end. It is needed in this format too.

Comment: show your code how you are getting results and how you want .

Comment: @lukehemingway I posted my answer as per your expected output check it

Answer (score 0):

Try with GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT like this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(staff_in.date_in
     , time_in 
     , staff_out.date_out
     , time_out)) 
  FROM staff_in 
  LEFT 
  JOIN staff_out 
    ON staff_in.user_id = staff_out.user_id
```

Comment: that works and puts them all on the same line but I need each one to have headers so in a separate cell.

Comment: Sorry for that each record print with header might not possible with GROUP_CONCAT